# Understanding JavaScript if statements combined with text box length

Tags: javascript, if-statement

initial apologies if the question is not worded the best. it's been a long day of JS and this is probably my final question of the day on here.
so here goes....

firstly, my code:
this is the JS

```
function passwordValidation(){

    var uname = document.getElementById("username").value;
    var pword = document.getElementById("password").value;

    var userTB = document.getElementById("username");
    var passTB = document.getElementById("password");
    var userTBLength = userTB.length;
    var passTBLength = passTB.length;

    var matchCol = "#009900";
    var noMatchCol = "#CC0000";
    var noBg = "#FFFFFF";



    if (uname.length < 1){
        password.style.backgroundColor = noBg;
    }else if (username.value == password.value){
        match = "Match!";
        password.style.backgroundColor = matchCol;
    } else if  (username.value != password.value{
        match = "No Match!";
        password.style.backgroundColor = noMatchCol;
    }
    document.getElementById("combination").innerHTML = match;
}
```

this is my html

```
<form>
Username: <input type="text" name="username" id="username" autocomplete="off" > <br><br>
Password:  <input type="text" name="password" id="password" onkeyup="passwordValidation()"> <br>
</form>
```

Basically it is a password validation form where if the passwords match, then it prints out match and the second field is turned green (this works). prints out no match and in red if it doesn't match (this also works).

my question, and a persnickety one it is, is regarding when both fields are blank. i.e length 0
it's unnecessary but I would like to achieve it to complete a successful day.
initially when the page loads up both the boxes are blank or white. when the user starts typing the second box turns green or red (this is great). issue is that when you delete values from both boxes it still stays green as obviously "blank" matches with "blank".

All I would like is that when they are blank they constantly have a white background and feel like my function should be achieving that...

Comment: Do you *really* want a username and password to match? Usually you have 2 password boxes and ensure *they* both match.

Comment: yeh sorry, i was initially doing something else and changed to this and couldn't be bothered to change it....

Comment: Why are you using `username.value` and `password.value` instead of `uname` and `pword`? Why set those variables if you're not going to use them?

Comment: @plalx do you understand the point of JS? it's to get as close as possible to ensuring the user enters something valid before it hits the database

Comment: @Barmar because I did use them and now am not and have not got rid of them yet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here could be that you are only calling the method `onkyup` of the password box, so this line:

```
if (uname.length < 1){
    password.style.backgroundColor = noBg;
```

Wont be being called for changes to the Username. Try adding the `onkeyup="passwordValidation()"` to the Username box too.

Comment: for some reason it does not even go to the second parts of the if statement i.e. the else if and the else. at the moment it does nothing regardless of what I type. match or no match. but if i keep everything the same and just take out the part regarding the length it works..

Comment: @BlueShark - you are missing a closing parenthesis on this line `} else if  (username.value != password.value{` - are you perhaps getting a JS error in the console?

Comment: @BlueShark - ha, no Ive just written too much javascript.

Answer (score 0):

This should fix the issue you are seeing.

```
function passwordValidation(){


    var userTB = document.getElementById("username");
    var passTB = document.getElementById("password");
    var uname = userTB.value;
    var pword = passTB.value;
    var userTBLength = userTB.length;
    var passTBLength = passTB.length;

    var matchCol = "#009900";
    var noMatchCol = "#CC0000";
    var noBg = "#FFFFFF";

    if (uname.length < 1){
        password.style.backgroundColor = noBg;
    }else { // Needed this so the call to innerHTML below wouldn't fail
        if (username.value == password.value){
            match = "Match!";
            password.style.backgroundColor = matchCol;
        } else if  (username.value != password.value){ // There was a missing ')' here
            match = "No Match!";
            password.style.backgroundColor = noMatchCol;
        }
        document.getElementById("combination").innerHTML = match;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What if you inserted another conditional to your else if statements regarding matches?

For example:

```
if (uname.length < 1 || (username.value === password.value && uname.length < 1) ){
    password.style.backgroundColor = noBg;
}else if (username.value === password.value && uname.length > 1){
    match = "Match!";
    password.style.backgroundColor = matchCol;
} else if  (username.value !== password.value{
    match = "No Match!";
    password.style.backgroundColor = noMatchCol;
}
```